# What is the best German translation for the useful word "issue" when describing a problem?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-german

I would like to say the following in German:

> Unfortunately, we could not reproduce the Save-as-XML **issue** that
>   you are experiencing on your computer.

but I cannot find a word other than "Problem" or "Fehler", which is too negative:

> Leider konnten wir das Save-as-XML **Problem** nicht reproduzieren, das
>   bei Ihnen auftritt.

Is there a word in German which has the same meaning as "issue" here, i.e. something that could be a "problem" but could also be something for more neutral, even positive?

Comment: It's a Problem, no matter which Euphemismus you are using. Honestly, "Problem" is the right word to use. The positive variant would be "Feature".

Comment: Either way, this is a *compound word*! Meaning, you need to put a hyphen: “Save-as-XML-Problem”. I know lots of people omit it but they are wrong.

Comment: I think in all the companies I have worked in the last decade the Germans simply used the word "Issue" when they were referring to what's an "issue" in English. `:)`

Comment: Would 'sorge' ever be used in this context?

Comment: @cheznead: No, *Sorge* quite directly translates to *concern* and refers to something a person is emotionally worried (*besorgt*) about. If you write down something about a *Sorge* of yours, it is normally not for technical support staff, but for your shrink.

Comment: AFAIR Microsoft started to claim in the 90-ies that Windows does not have "bugs", but "issues". Anyway, what about "Angelegenheit" (which is very neutral)? @sbi: People doing that either just don't know what the word means, or they want to sound more intellectual (IMHO).

Comment: @U.Windl: People doing this are programmers, deal with an issue tracking system every day, don't know a good translation either, but have to talk about it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In this specific case the word *Verhalten* (behaviour in English) could fit:

> Leider konnten wir das Verhalten bei Save-as-XML nicht reproduzieren, das bei Ihnen auftritt.

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility for a "neutral" expression would be "Situation" - which has a rather deliberately vague feel to it in German, not unlike "issue" in English :)

> Leider konnten wir die von Ihnen beschriebene Save-as-XML-Situation
>   nicht reproduzieren.

Still, splattne's suggestion sounds best to me, esp. in an IT-related context. (+1 for splattne, btw) :)

Also, +1 for the question - "issue" is a neat little expression that we're lacking in German.

(OT: recently heard a hilarious use of the term: "B*tch, please; you've got more issues than Vogue." - I laughed so hard I cried)

Answer (score 8):

In general I think *Problem* and *Fehler* fits best in this topic and you can use them for sure. I know the concern of some people that both words sounds too negative, but if something does not work it is a *problem* or *mistake*. So why beating around the bush? Just mention what it really is. A bug.

If you don't want to use them, it's hard to find a good word that fits in this case. At least I don't know any. Maybe you can replace *issue* with *behavior* (as [splattne also mentions](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3873/1224)) or *difficulty* (whereas the latter does not really fit and is negative yet).

> Leider konnten wir das von ihnen beschriebene Verhalten der Save-as-XML-Funktion nicht nachvollziehen.
>
> Leider konnten wir das von ihnen beschriebene Verhalten beim Speichern im XML-Format nicht nachvollziehen.

You can also reword your sentence by specifying the actual error:

- If it is about the export result (e.g. incomplete), then you could rephrase it

  > Leider konnten wir die Ausgabe, wie sie bei Ihnen auftritt, nicht nachvollziehen.
- If an error message occurs, then you could say

  > Leider ist es uns nicht möglich, die von ihnen beschriebene Fehlermeldung auszulösen.

Comment: +1 I think "auslösen" is a perfectly good verb here.

Answer (score 5):

Im geschilderten Fall halte ich `Problem` für angemessen und kundenfreundlich, weil man signalisiert, dass man das Phänomen ernstnimmt, und für ein Problem hält. Phänomen ist ein traditionsreiches Fremdwort:

> Leider konnten wir das Save-as-XML-Phänomen, das bei Ihnen auftritt, nicht reproduzieren.

Answer (score 3):

2 Jahre zu spät aber im Internet steht alles bis in alle Ewigkeit also hier mein Vorschlag:

Schwierigkeit

Geht sehr gut zusammen mit auftreten.

> Die Schwierigkeiten treten bei uns nicht auf.

Klingt vielleicht etwas weniger dramatisch als Problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another appropriate word in this case would be *Angelegenheit* which means 'matter,' 'issue,' or simply 'point.' Alternatively: *Problematik*, *Sachverhalt*

Answer (score 1):

For an IT related auditorium the best is to not translate "Issue", if you really want to translate it, I would use "Problem", as it is not as negative as "Error".

I would not use the suggested word "Situation", it is not common in this context.

Comment: Of course you *must* translate it. *Issue* is not a common word such as *E-Mail*, *Download*, etc. Moreover it sounds odd, using *issue* in a German sentence. Pay attention on the fact that your contact does not necessarily knows English. Example: A customer who only use your system. He reports an error and you answer him in *Denglish*?! No, please don't!

Comment: @Em1: Issue is common for IT related persons, especially developers will know what an issue is and they will know the difference between an issue and a bug. Of course you would translate it for a customer.

Comment: @Feroc Of course they know what an *issue* is but it isn't in regular use. I am developer and I only hear this word when talking with our Americans fellows. Though you can use it in *pure German* when referring to a context where the word *issue* is given (e.g. in a database: *Hast du auch den issue Eintrag korrigiert*). Bug, however, is much more common but have to be translated, too.

Comment: @Em1 Guess the vocabulary of our companies is different then. For the last two companies I worked for, issue was quite a common word to use. Just my first company never ever used it. But I guess this is more about customers anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly more colloquial term which can also be used outside of IT:

> Die Sache mit "Save-as-XML", die Sie gemeldet hatten, konnten wir nicht reproduzieren.

I wouldn't necessarily write this in an official Email, though.